# How to find out which particular row in a UITableView received a force-touch event?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to implement 3D touch on a UITableView. The following code inside a subclassed UITableView works:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if touch.force <= (touch.maximumPossibleForce / 2) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    else {
        print("force touch called !!!")
    }
}
```

**However, how I know what particular row within the table is force-touched?**

The touch.view is identified as a "UITableViewCellContentView" object while debugging, but this class does not exist in the UIKit. Casting it causes a "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x107cbab80) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x107cbab30)." runtime error.

**How to find out which particular row in a UITableView received a force-touch event?** I'm using Swift 4.2 and iOS 12.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content view is a view inside the cell, you can't simply cast it to a `UITableViewCell` as it is an unrelated type.

You can use [`indexPathForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614874-indexpathforrow) to convert a CGPoint into an `IndexPath`.  You will need to [convert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-location) the touch point in the table view's coordinate system, rather than the content view.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if touch.force <= (touch.maximumPossibleForce / 2) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    else {
        print("force touch called !!!")
        let tablePoint = touch.location(in:self)
        if let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at:tablePoint) {
            print("\(indexPath.row) touched")
        }
    }
}
```

Depending what you are trying to do, you might find it easier to handle the force touch in your view controller via [`registerForPreviewing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621463-registerforpreviewing) and `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`